# Get current category image?

Tags: magento2, category

How can **I retrieve the category image (url) in the `list.phtml`** file?

I am currently using this to get the current category:

```
<?php $category = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category'); ?>
```

But I don't know how to get the image url using `$category`?

Comment: Avoiding using Object Manager directly in template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can try with `$category->getImageUrl())`

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/image.phtml`